# Best Practices for Table Structure

Tags: database, relational-database

Consider a table Employee, employee table stores various employee details.
One of such detail is Type of the Employee

The type of employee would be

1. Permenant
2. Contract
3. Freelance

There could be many employee types

So I name the column in Employee table as 'EmployeeType'

My Application has a table called ApplicationSettings(Id, Code, Description), I prefer to put the Employee Type into this table, So the value of Code field will be stored in Employee Table for Employee Type.

What i want is an advice from you what will be a better way to organise this structure.
The above method, or create a new Table called EmployeeType ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use what you have proposed if you add a CodeType field to your code table.  That way when you just want your employee types you can query it like:

```
    SELECT Id, Code, Description FROM Codes WHERE CodeType='EmployeeType'
```

Its also perfectly acceptable (and maybe a litter clearer for future people looking at your database) to have a separate employeetype table.

Comment: What should be the name of column in Employee table? EmployeeTypeId or EmployeeType ??,Please suggest

Comment: Ah, depends on which table you end up storing the type in.  Typical pattern is tableNameId. So if you use your code table, use CodeId.

Comment: Or if you have multiple codes referenced perhaps (FieldTableId) so going back to the code table TypeCodeId